# possible to return list of dict instead of a list when using for in? django

Tags: python, arrays, django, list, dictionary

I have a code which returns a list, which looks something like this

`[user.name for user in Model.field.filter()]`

I know this would return me a list of user name but I am wondering if it would be possible to return `list` of `dict`?

such as

```
[
    {'name': 'name1', 'email': 'email1'},
    {'name': 'name2', 'email': 'email2'}
]
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just do something like `[{'name':user.name, 'email': user.email} for user in Model.field.filter()]`?

Comment: What is the output of [user.name for user in Model.field.filter()]

Comment: @PaulRooney you are right, that does work, I was over looking and this is perfect...do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it? thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to just build a `dict` for each entry in a list comprehension.

e.g.

```
[{'name':user.name, 'email': user.email} for user in Model.field.filter()]
```

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary would have unique keys where you have listed 'name' and 'email' and would not work if you are repeating for many names/emails. Not mentioning that you cant 'return' a dict from a list, you can however [create one](https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/three-ways-of-creating-dictionaries-in-python/). Now, if you have keys for your name and email feild then the dict would be created like this `namedict = {"key1":"name1","key2":"name2"}`. I would seperate it into two dicts, one for name and one for email. Only then can you return a name from the dict by going `namedict["key1"]`

If your "name" variable is not so variable ;) (as in you want it to be "name" for each of your unique "name1"s then I think using pandas dataframes would be more ideal. This way you only need to add "name" once, as the header for the list of names, and can have it in the same variable as the emails, where you would do the same. You [make a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) by going:

```
d= {'name': ["name1", "name2"], 'email': ["email1", "email2"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I included the dict section to answer your actual question but overall from what I can see, dataframes would better suit your purpose.